# Phone memory contacts disappeared but can be searched in Dialer

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts, 5.1-lollipop, phone-app

All my contacts that were saved in phone memory suddenly disappeared. They would not show up in the Contacts app, but are somehow searchable using the Dialer app (using T9 shortcuts - for example to find Mr. Dinglesplat type 3464 and get it suggested.)

I have tried many a contacts recovery apps, none of which could help me a bit.
I had majority of my contacts backed up so it is not a real issue, but it just feels weird because they are still in the Dialer suggestion list.

Is there any method this Dialer cache be recovered? **How long will this cache remain?**

Also, I had to reinstall recovery, and erase the cache partition of my phone recently, but the behavior hasn't changed. I didn't have those contacts before and after, and they are still in the Dialer suggestion list.

Comment: You should Check your contacts display option. maybe your phone contact display option be disabled.

Comment: @MalvikChauhan Sadly that's not the case. I have it set to all contacts.